# Maven multiproject eclipse import gets all references right but misses them at runtime.

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

Hello all I'm trying to get started with maven and eclipse.

I have some experience with spring, hibernate and maven for a single maven project so far.  What I try to achieve is to separate my project into 3 projects representing the classic layers. Web, Service and DAO. I want to build a proper project stub managed by maven. 
To get started I created the Web project and the DAO project and I'm already hitting a wall. My maven project has the following structure:

```
-SuperProject
--Web
--DAO
```

Here is the pom of the parent:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maventest01.test01</groupId>
  <artifactId>test01</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <test01-data.version>1.0</test01-data.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>

  <module>../test01-data</module>
  <module>../test01-web</module>

  </modules>

  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>test01</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  <!-- test01-data Dependecies -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>



    <!-- test01-web Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>


  <build>

  <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is the pom of the web layer:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maventest01.test01.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>test01-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>test01-web</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
  <groupId>com.maventest01.test01</groupId>
  <artifactId>test01</artifactId>
  <relativePath>../test01</relativePath>
  <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <test01-data.version>1.0</test01-data.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>${junit.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.maventest01.test01.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>test01-data</artifactId>
          <version>${test01-data.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>


  </dependencies>


  <build>

        <plugins>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>              <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>

                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the pom of DAO layer:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.maventest01.test01.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>test01-data</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>test01-data</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.maventest01.test01</groupId>
        <artifactId>test01</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../test01</relativePath>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>




    <build>

        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Once I completed the pom files I did a

```
mvn install
```

then a

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

After this I imported the 3 projects in Eclipse. As existing java projects not as maven projects. (I want to use maven independently from eclipse and vice versa).

Now by checking the deployment assembly of the eclipse project all jars are properly referenced as well as the DAO project. The only thing I needed to do is add the DAO project to the Tomcat classpath. So far everything seemed ok.

To test this configuration i'm building a simple login form. In the web project the controller returning the index page I create an instance of UserDAO because I figured this triggers an the Exception. 
See the controller code and the dispatcher-servlet.xml:

Controller:

```
package com.maventest01.test01.web.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.maventest01.test01.data.dao.impl.UserDAO;
import com.maventest01.test01.data.model.UserEntity;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndexPage(ModelMap model) {

            UserDAO userdao = new UserDAO();
        model.addAttribute("user", new UserEntity());

        return "index";
    }    
}
```

dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.maventest01.test01.web" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Eclipse gives no errors, but at runtime I get the exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
    com.maventest01.test01.web.controllers.IndexController.getIndexPage(IndexController.java:19)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

It seems to me at runtime at server level the dependencies are not available anymore. Now if I want to inject the DAO using the @Autowired annotation and by adding the following line to the dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.maventest01.test01.data.dao.impl.UserDAO" />
```

I have the exception:

```
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 30 16:26:37 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:554)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Again it seems to me spring cannot find the DAO project. Because if I remove the line:

from the dispatcher-servlet.xml the code runs. But of course cannot work because the DAO piece is missing.

So what am I missing? I feel like I messed up some pom configuration. Somehow the DAO pom is not available to the tomcat even it is referenced in the deployment assembly of the web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not add Maven support to your projects in Eclipse, then the Eclipse WTP plugin has no chance to know and collect the dependencies of your projects and deploy them for you. If you do, then the m2WTP plugin will provide the necessary dependency information, based on the contents of your POM, to the WTP plugin and it will deploy them.

I think you are creating a whole lot of problems for yourself by not using the Eclipse-Maven integration.

Also, you should not list the dependencies of your modules in the parent POM unless they are shared dependencies and you want to fix the version for all modules (needs to be enforced, too).

The path to your module in the parent POM is `test01-data`, not `../test01-data`. Same for the other module.

The path to your parent POM is just `..`, not `../test01`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I also stopped trying not using the m2eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The best Maven support these days come from within Eclipse, instead of having configuration files written by an external process.

Ensure that the maven projects are available on your file system and use the File->Import->Existing Maven projects to import them.

(Note: You will need an Eclipse distribution with the m2e plugin - the standard Java and Java EE flavors has it).